# Read word list from text file with control word length

Tags: c#

How can read word list text file but check word length before reading words?

```
var s = File.ReadAllText("words_alpha.txt").Where(r=>r.ToString().Length<6 &&
        r.ToString()!="\n"
```

Comment: Do you intend to split the input into words before checking the length of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead

```
 var s = File.ReadAllLines(@"words_alpha.txt")
                      .Select((x, i) => new { Line = x, LineNumber = i })
                      .Where(x => x.Line.Length > 6 &&  x.ToString()!="\n")
                      .ToList();
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but i just want my words in list what should i change in  code?

Comment: Done TextBox1.Text = s[0].x; ty

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("words_alpha.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     if(line.Length > 6)
     {
        //YOUR CODE
     }
}
```

Comment: long time for loading all text that's why i want put filter on it